# How use ext:typoscript_rendering with ext:from in TYPO3

Tags: ajax, forms, typo3

I have on the page a form (based on `ext:form`) like the content element. I want to run the form when I click on the button without not reload a page. I know that I can use this `ext:typoscript_rendering` but I still do not find an example, how to do it.

**I already created and added `JS`**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.frame-type-form_formframework').on('click', '#ajax-submit', function (e) {
        var ajaxUrl = $(this).data('ajaxuri');
        if (ajaxUrl !== undefined && ajaxUrl !== '') {
            e.preventDefault();
            var container = 'formaddnewpost-container-348';
            var formData = new FormData(this); // ???
            $.ajax({
                url: ajaxUrl,
                type: 'post',
                data: formData, // ???
                success: function (result) {
                    var ajaxDom = $(result).find('#' + container);
                    $('#' + container).replaceWith(ajaxDom);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**I add to form:**

```
additionalAttributes="{data-ajaxuri:'{t:uri.action(additionalParams:\'{tx_news_pi1:{controller:News,action:detail,news:newsItem}}\',contextRecord:\'currentPage\',extensionName:\'form\',pluginName:\'formframework\',controller:\'FormFrontend\',action:\'render\')->f:format.htmlentities()}'}"
```

And I add to button:

```
<f:form.button additionalAttributes="{data-ajaxuri:'{t:uri.action(additionalParams:\'{tx_news_pi1:{controller:News,action:detail,news:newsItem}}\',contextRecord:\'currentPage\',extensionName:\'form\',pluginName:\'formframework\',controller:\'FormFrontend\',action:\'render\')->f:format.htmlentities()}'}" property="__currentPage" value="{form.nextPage.index}" id="ajax-submit" class="btn btn-primary">{formvh:translateElementProperty(element: form.currentPage, renderingOptionProperty: 'nextButtonLabel')}</f:form.button>
```

**I tried**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.frame-type-form_formframework').on('click', '#ajax-submit', function (e) {
        var ajaxUrl = $(this).data('ajaxuri');
        if (ajaxUrl !== undefined && ajaxUrl !== '') {
            e.preventDefault();
            var formIdSelector = '<f:format.raw>{form.formDefinition.identifier}</f:format.raw>';
            var containerIdSelector = formIdSelector + '-container';
            $.ajax({
                url: ajaxUrl,
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('#' + formIdSelector).serialize(),
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    var ajaxDom = $(response).find('#' + containerIdSelector);
                    $('#' + containerIdSelector).replaceWith(ajaxDom);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

...and this working well. Now the `form` running without reloading the page but data from the form not sending.

Now staying question, **how to send data from the form and get the result?**

Comment: The issue you are facing is not related to typoscript_rendering, but to form serialization. So maybe check what FormData is and how to get the from values out of it

Comment: @helhum thanks! Maybe you have the experience to work your 'ext:typoscript_rendering' and with 'ext:form' I do not know how to combine them.  Maybe you have an example or you can to direct me on to there where I can to read about it more.

Comment: Have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044798/how-to-use-formdata-for-ajax-file-upload

Comment: Yes, I saw and did try everything to use it but it is without positive results. I have seen it yet https://www.comuno.net/blog/detail/formular-mit-typoscript-rendering-per-ajax-verschicken/ and tried it but not works for me I do not understand why. I find nothing about `ext:typoscript_rendering` and  `ext:form`. I did not find valid examples of your `ext: typoscript_rendering`, but only `ext: new` pagination